# Can you make the spacing around \middle separators the same as spacing around array lines?

Tags: spacing, amsmath, matrices, arrays, delimiters

I’d like to generate something like this code’s output:

```latex
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c}
0 & 3 & -2 & 8 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 4 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 3
\end{array} \right]
```

But by using `matrix` instead. Unfortunately, this code:

```latex
\left[ \begin{matrix}
0 & 3 & -2 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix} \middle| \begin{matrix}
8 \\
4 \\
3
\end{matrix} \right]
```

produces matrices that are too closely spaced around the middle |.

Is there a way to achieve the same spacing as with the array?

Comment: Frqankly, the array version is more logical.  The main advantage of matrix is that you don't have to count the columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to be absolutely precise, use can add just the exact space, it's used to sep columns via `\hspace\arraycolsep`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$$
\left[ \begin{matrix}
0 & 3 & -2 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix} \hspace\arraycolsep\middle|\hspace\arraycolsep \begin{matrix}
8 \\
4 \\
3
\end{matrix} \right]
$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you can simply use `~` space character around `\middle|` that's also looks ok for me (but not as precise as other spacing in columns).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$$
\left[ \begin{matrix}
0 & 3 & -2 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix} ~\middle|~ \begin{matrix}
8 \\
4 \\
3
\end{matrix} \right]
$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, avoid `$$` in LaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

Reading your question, I realized that the little-used package called `spalign` meets your requirements. For the matrices there are good options and the package is not difficult to understand. I placed your numbers in the right r option and as you see the sign is well placed with the other numbers. If there had been another minus sign it would have been the same thing. The code is really stripped down to its essentials.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,spalign}


\begin{document}
$\spaligndelims{[}{]}\spalignaugmatn[r]{1}{0 3 -2 8; 1 1 0 4; 1 0 1 3}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{bmatrixp}{O{1} b}
 {
  \schuelermine_bmatrixp:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
 {}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \schuelermine_bmatrixp:nn
 {
  % split at \\
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ } { #2 }
  % check for a trailing \\; if the last item is empty
  % do nothing, otherwise add back the row
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_if_empty:VF \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_put_right:NV \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl }
  % now count the number of columns in each row
  \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
   {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpb_seq { & } { ##1 }
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { \int_max:nn { \l_tmpa_int } { \seq_count:N \l_tmpb_seq } }
   }
  % we can make the array
  \left[
  \begin{array}{ @{} *{\int_eval:n { \l_tmpa_int - #1 }}{c} | *{#1}{c} @{} }
  #2
  \end{array}
  \right]
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bmatrixp}
0 & 3 & -2 & 8 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 4 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 3
\end{bmatrixp}
\]

\[
\begin{bmatrixp}[2]
0 & 3 & -2 & 8 & a \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 4 & b \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 3 & c \\
\end{bmatrixp}
\]

\end{document}
```

The idea is to examine the environment's content so to be able to count the number of columns. At that point we can add `|` at the right spot in the column specification. The optional argument tells how many columns should be at the right of the partition symbol.

[image]

However doing

```
\left[\begin{array}{@{} ccc | c @{}}
0 & 3 & -2 & 8 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 4 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 3
\end{array}\right]
```

might be easier.